# From the letters of the word $BENZENE$, how many distinct 6 letter words can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

From the letters of the word $BENZENE$, how many distinct 6 letter words can be formed?

I have used the following approach:

For choosing $6$ letters we have following two possible sets (multi-set) of letters

$S_1 = \{B,E,N,Z,E,N\}$ or $S_2 = \{B,E,N,Z,E,E\}$

so I am getting $\frac{6!}{2! \times 2!} + \frac{6!}{3!} = 300$.

Am I correct? what could be other way for getting the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have not considered all possible ways to delete a letter:

- Delete B or Z: $\binom6{3,2,1}=60$ each
- Delete N: $\binom6{3,1,1,1}=120$
- Delete E: $\binom6{2,2,1,1}=180$

So the correct answer is $60+60+120+180=420$. A shorter way to get there is to note that each $6$-letter word corresponds to a unique permutation of the original $7$ letters by adding the one missing letter, so there are $\binom7{3,2,1,1}=420$ words.

Comment: I think I am missing something really obvious but shouldn't the answer just be $7!$? As the number of $r-$permutations of $n$ objects is given by $n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)$. And so the number of ways to make $6$ letter words from a set of $7$ letters is just a $6-$permutation of $7$ elements.

Comment: @Seeker Some items are identical.

Comment: Oh right. Just realised the three E's and the $N's$.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation.